# Uncaught TypeError: $scope.mvp.$setUntouched is not a function angularjs 1.4

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am getting following error while trying to remove ngTouch classes from my form. This error clearly reflects that I am using `angularjs1.4` which already has this function. However I am still getting this error

```
$scope.mvp.$setUntouched()
VM3202:1 Uncaught TypeError: $scope.mvp.$setUntouched is not a function
    at n.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:55)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:954:21)
    at n.$scope.resetPerson (http://localhost:55607/app/controller/personController.js:20:19)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:212:83), <anonymous>:2:224)
    at http://localhost:55607/Scripts/angular-touch.min.js:12:197
    at n.$get.n.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:134:493)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:135:217)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:55607/Scripts/angular-touch.min.js:12:179)
```

Here is my CSS

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched.ng-pristine {
    border-color: #FA787E;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FA787E;
  }

input.ng-valid.ng-touched {
    border-color: #78FA89;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #78FA89;
}
```

Controller reset method

```
$scope.resetPerson = function () {
            angular.copy({}, mvp);
            $scope.init();
            $scope.mvp.$setPristine();
            $scope.mvp.$setUntouched();
        }
```

Form definition

```
<form novalidate name="mvp" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

Is it a css issue, the way I defined?

**EDIT**

I was able to make it working. Issue was in my reset method in controller.

```
$scope.resetPerson = function () {
            angular.copy({}, $scope.person); //this fixed the issue
            $scope.init();
            $scope.mvp.$setPristine();
            $scope.mvp.$setUntouched();
        }
```

My model was `$scope.person` and I was setting `angular.copy({}, mvp);` instead which means I was setting form mvp = {}. However I didn't understand why did I get error $setUntouched is not a function

Comment: which angular version you are using?

Comment: Angular 1.4.3, its present in error as well which clearly means browser is reading angularjs file

Comment: Would you mind to create a plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your form is not being sent to your angular function by it's name.

```
 $scope.master = {};
 $scope.reset = function(mvp) {
    if (mvp) {
       mvp.$setPristine();
       mvp.$setUntouched();
    }
       $scope.person = angular.copy($scope.master);
 };
```

I tried to answer your question with a question. It did not work out (: This one should ... let me know

**It was undefined because you set your form to an object with the copy and setUntouched is a form controller and not an obj controller**

Comment: I think I am able to resolve the issue. However not exactly what you mentioned. I am getting mvp on my reset function. This is something I checked using debugger. The issue was with angular.copy command on my controller. I will add my working controller function. It would be great if you can answer why did I get error `$setUntouched` is not a function

Comment: It may be because you have the copy statement before the `setUntouched`. You are setting it to an empty object then doing `setUntouched`. At that point it is undefined because you are not applying to a form but to an empty object. Thats why in my example I moved the copy statement below. That'd be my guess.

Comment: It's still opposite. Please see my edit. It's working for me now. Just trying to understand why it gave me error $setUntouched is not a function

Comment: It was undefined because you set your form to an object with the copy and  `setUntouched` is a form controller and not an obj controller ... ahh nvm. I am not  gonna repeat my self.  It is hard to help some people who knows everything ... good luck bro I am glad you figured out how to fix it. I am out (:

Comment: This seems to be a very valid point, can you please modify your answer so that it can be helpful for others as well. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I didn't read your second part of the comment. As I understood the issue with the first part. I am still learning angular and when I saw documentation of angular.copy. I could relate it with your comment why I was getting error setUntouched is not a function. i..e because form controller has already been nullified. However in your current example, you need not set it to a copy of master. This is where I messed up in explaining that mvp is my form and not a model and I am supposed to set `model = {}` but not to form. Modified your answer to reflect the same.